# How are multiple ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback methods evaluated?

Tags: .net, x509certificate

How is the following code evaluated?

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ValidateRemoteCertificateA;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ValidateRemoteCertificateB;
```

Given an HttpWebRequest, is it enough if one of the Validator methods returns true, or do they both have to return true? i.e.

```
ValidateRemoteCertificateA && ValidateRemoteCertificateB
```

or

```
ValidateRemoteCertificateA || ValidateRemoteCertificateB
```

?

Cheers,
tamberg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will use the return value of the last delegate added, in all cases.

`ServerCertificateValidationCallback` is a [multicast delegate](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/08/delegates-vs-function-pointers-addendum.html) property.
Writing `ServerCertificateValidationCallback += x` appends `x` to its invocation list.
The return value of a multicast delegate is the return value of the last delegate in its list.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the straight forward explanation. This seems to be rather a rather odd design given that multiple HttpWebRequests can happen from different modules that are probably not even aware of each other.

Comment: Yes; [they shouldn't use global state to manage a local problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/11/9193695.aspx).

Comment: @SLaks - Do you have any recommendations as to how to address this as a local problem instead? The ServerCertificateValidationCallback is the only way I've come across to do custom validation on certs like this, but it seems too broad in its scope for my purposes (adding custom validation to ignore ssl errors in a very specific set of circumstances in one method). Thanks =)

Comment: Indeed. HttpWebRequest has a member for this nowadays, but they failed to add the same thing to FtpWebRequest. Still looking for a better way to address this. It's a ridiculous design, particularly with the last added delegate always gettings its way.